# Why settings in my config.php aren't overriding settings in the CP

Tags: database, config

It's my understanding that settings in the config.php override any settings in the control panel.

Background:
I have copied a site over so it runs from another domain (with the view of closing down the original site). I want both sites to use the same database so they display the same content but change the site's general configs and paths. If I changed paths (like theme path) in the control panel then that seems to affect the other site as I think these setting are stored in the DB.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, config values override the database values. So my guess is that the other site is not properly reading the config value (not set, or mis-spelled?).

Comment: If you load the CP for both sites side by side, do you see different values in the CP? If so, the two CPs are reading their respective config.php files. If not, please provide more details on your server & vhosts, settings, etc.

Comment: Thank you both. It's working. Also, I was confused by the site name which wasn't changing. Apparently, it's a know bug so I have downloaded this add-on to deal with the specific problem of site name: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/override_site_name

Comment: Yes, site name doesn't update when added to config.php

Comment: How can I mark this post as "answered"?

Comment: If you post an answer (rather than a comment) that details the solution you'll be able to mark it as accepted, though I think the site does enforce a delay between posting an answer and accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working. I was partly confused by the site_name which wasn't changing. Apparently, it's a known bug so I have downloaded this add-on to deal with that specific problem of site_name: devot-ee.com/add-ons/override_site_name –